# Override setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR) in Viewport Meta?

Tags: android, eclipse, webview, viewport

Hope someone can help with this.  I'm using webview and want to set ZoomDensity to far and .setLoadWithOverviewMode(true) - but only for pages that don't have a viewport width defined in the meta tag.

The goal is that if a page is loaded with no viewport meta tag, it will scale the page to fit the mobile screen, but if there is a viewport width set, say 240, it will ignore the zoom density and scale using the meta-defined setting.

```
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

It seems that whenever ZoomDensity.FAR is set, everything appears smaller on the screen (zoomed out), even though my meta tag says:

If I remove the zoomdensity line from the java app it works great on my mobile site, but won't scale-down a wide regular site.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
webview.setInitialScale(1);
```

will fully zoom out any page to fit the webview when combined with setLoadWithOverviewMode(true) and setUseWideViewPort(true), allowing you to remove setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR) altogether.